# fPortfolio: Error when running LPM optimization

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

When I run a `mean` `LPM optimization` I get the following error:

> Error in match.fun(spec@model$param$tau) : 
>         'spec@model$param$tau' is not a function, character or symbol

I have already set the estimator to `lpmEstimator` and type to `LPM`. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `getAnywhere("lpmEstimator")` it is necessary to specify parameters for `fAssets::assetsLPM` that is used to get the estimations.

This works here:

```
lppData  <-  100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6]
spec <- portfolioSpec()
spec@model$type="LPM"
#getAnywhere("lpmEstimator")
#lpmEstimator(lppData)
#fAssets::assetsLPM(lppData,apply(lppData,2,mean),a=2)
getEstimator(spec) #to retrieve the current setting 
setEstimator(spec)="lpmEstimator"
spec@model$param$tau= colMeans #the target return.
spec@model$param$a=2

#optimize, without shortselling
frontier3 <- portfolioFrontier(lppData, spec = spec,constraints="LongOnly");
getWeights(frontier3)
frontierPoints(frontier3)

# > frontierPoints(frontier3)
# targetRisk targetReturn
# 1  0.12609343 0.0000406634
# 2  0.11470167 0.0017901986
# 3  0.10794259 0.0035397338
# 4  0.10303948 0.0052892689
# 5  0.10060581 0.0070388041

# 9  0.10151888 0.0140369448
# 10 0.10475357 0.0157864800
# 11 0.10911567 0.0175360152

# 18 0.16347904 0.0297827615
# 19 0.17379682 0.0315322967
# 20 0.18448599 0.0332818318
# 21 0.19548564 0.0350313670
# 22 0.20674621 0.0367809022

# 29 0.29024846 0.0490276485
# 30 0.30260866 0.0507771836
# 31 0.31503911 0.0525267188
# 32 0.32753181 0.0542762540

# 49 0.55299710 0.0840183521
# 50 0.56844009 0.0857678860
# attr(,"control")
# targetRisk targetReturn         auto 
# "Cov"       "mean"       "TRUE"
```

### EDIT

If you want your own `tau` you will need a function that assign it to each asset (so depends on your data). In this case one way would be doing:

```
mtau=function(x)rep(0.04,ncol(x))
spec@model$param$tau=mtau #the target return.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is colMeans and what does it contain?

Comment: I know what tau is, its the minimum acceptable rate of return that an investor wants in an LPM optimization. I want to set it to 4%, or 0.04. How do I do that? If i set `spec@model$param$tau <- 0.04`, it gives the same error

Comment: See `?colMeans. It computes the means of your `data.frame`, and in this case uses that as `tau`.  For your own `tau` see the edit.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it's still not working. I have an object X with 11 columns, 1st column date, 2:11 are the stocks. 47 rows. Of course, I used as.timeSeries(X). How would you define tau for this? If I define tau to mimic the size of this object I get the following error: `Error in eval(call, parent.frame()) : 
  dims [product 470] do not match the length of object [22090]`

Comment: Omit the `date` column when passing the data.frame (x[,2:11])